# Codeigniter possible re-direct/autoload?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeIgniter and I have come across a problem whilst following a tutorial; I am trying to build a basic CMS using codeigniter but I keep getting the following error:

> string(42) "/var/www/html/trc.better2know.net/httpdocs" Fatal error:
>   Class 'Frontend_Controller' not found in
>   /var/www/html/trc.better2know.net/application/controllers/Welcome.php
>   on line 4

Ive got the following autoload in my config files:

```
 function __autoload($classname) {
    if (strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        $file = APPPATH . 'controller/' . $classname . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Also this htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#Send requests via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I have tried moving the Frontend_Controller into the same file as MY_Controller but still no joy, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Tell us, Which version of CI are you using? Please try only 'Frontend' as Class name and file name.

Comment: Usually that autoload function is set to use/load `core` directory files/classes. I.E. `$file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $classname . '.php';`. Beside that, you are using directory name singular although dir name is pluralized. Try with `$file = APPPATH . 'controllers/' . $classname . '.php';`.

Comment: Thanks, I did miss an 'S' but the roblem still persists, ive tried moving my controllers to libraries and again, no luck. im getting an error of the Frontend_Controller class does not exist but i caant see why im being thrown this error, ive put a clean install of codeigniter onto my server and triple checked all my config code

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter has its own auto-loading feature. You don't need to create one of your own. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html

Comment: still no luck, its trying to load my custom class Frontend_Controller from the wrong directory hence why i tried a custom autoloader

Comment: From what i read in your question, maybe you should take some time to fully understand the behavior of MVC (Model View Controller) in Codeigniter. 

You said: 

I have tried moving the Frontend_Controller into the same file as MY_Controller but still no joy.

You can't have two controllers on the same file. To use new controllers you have to see routing. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: So your telling me I can only have 1 controller in each directory? I am new to the MVC framework so an advice is useful. I currently have 2 controllers in the libraries folder: Frontend_Controller and Admin_Controller. when I load the frontend controller from my welcome page it now works finebut when i try load the admin controller Im getting the following:

Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Controller' not found in /var/www/html/trc.better2know.net/application/controllers/Welcome.php on line 4

but if i change the class in Welcome to extends Frontend_Controller I dont get this error

Comment: No you can have as many controllers you want in a directory, I understood something else, sorry.

Comment: nevermind, ive figured it out, it was my folder structure that was the problem. Thanks